# Prove the continuity of this function.

Tags: calculus, continuity, lebesgue-integral

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a Lebesgue-mesurable and bounded function.

Suppose there exists Lebesgue-measurable set $E$ s.t. $\text{supp} (f)\subset E$ and $m(E)<\infty$.

Difine $g:(0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}.$ by $g(y)=\displaystyle\int_{[0,y]} f(x) dx$.

Then, prove that $g$ is continuous.

***Mt attempt***

From the supposition of $f$, there exist a sequence of simple functions $\{ \phi_n \}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ and $K>0$ and Lebesgue-measurable set $E$ such that

$・|\phi_n (x)|\leqq K$

$・m(E)<\infty$

・supp$(\phi_n)$ $\subset E$

$・\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty} \phi_n(x)=f(x)$ a.e.

(This fact is already proved.)

For $t>s,$

\begin{align}
|F(t)-F(s)|&=\left|\displaystyle\int_{[0,t]} f(x) dx-\displaystyle\int_{[0,s]} f(x) dx\right|\\
&=\left|\displaystyle\int_{[0,s]} f(x) dx
+\displaystyle\int_{(s,t]} f(x) dx
-\displaystyle\int_{[0,s]} f(x) dx\right|\\
&=\left|\displaystyle\int_{(s,t]} f(x) dx\right|\\
&=\left|\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{(s,t]} \phi_n(x) dx\right|(\because \text{ the bounded convergence theorem})\\
\end{align}

I'm stacked here.

I'd like you to give me some ideas.

Comment: $g$ is Lipschitz-continuous. Let $K=\sup \{f(x):x>0\}. $ If $0<y<z$ then $ |g(z)-g(y)|=|\int_y^z f(x)dx|\le \int_y^z|f(x)|dx\le \int_y^zKdx=K|z-y|.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $y_n \to y$ then $\chi_{[0,y_n]} (x)\to \chi_{[0,y]}(x)$ for all $x \neq y$. Hence $f(x)\chi_{[0,y_n]} (x)\to f(x)\chi_{[0,y]}(x)$ a.e. and $|f(x)\chi_{[0,y_n]} (x)| \leq C$ where $C$ is a bound for $|f|$. Hence DCT can be applied to see that $g(y_n)=\int\chi_{[0,y_n]} f(x)dx \to \int\chi_{[0,y]} f(x)dx=g(y)$.

Comment: Why does $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty} \chi_{[0,y_n]} (x)= \chi_{[0,\lim_{n\to \infty} \ y_n]}(x)$ hold? And if $x=y,$ why doesn't this  hold?

Comment: Consider $x<y$ and $x>y$ separately and use definition of limit. For $x=y$ it can fail: Take $y_n =x-\frac  1n$ @EPA